# Already Exists in AKS : Re-deployment Issue

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I was redeploying a Kubernetes pod on AKS but I am getting this already exists as an issue. Even after I deleted the namespace. How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Strange, do you see the namespace hanging around even after deleting it ? Has it got deleted completely ?

Comment: Looks like you're not deploying just a pod

Comment: I created a Namespace in Kubernetes and then created a pod in it. But due to some unexpected reasons, I deleted the namespace using kubectl delete command. Now that I want to re-deploy the same Kubernetes pod I am getting this error.

Comment: No the @ChandraSekar the namespace was deleted

Comment: Sounds like you may be running `kubectl create ...` instead of `kubectl apply ...`.  If the resources already exist and you're just trying to update/re-deploy, then you should use `kubectl apply` to "update" the deployment.  If you use `kubectl create`, then it will fail with this error message if the resources already exist.